# What are the main patterns and/or attributes that make an application RESTful?

Tags: design-patterns, rest

What are the main patterns and/or attributes that make an application RESTful?

Comment: Good post by Martin Fowler about REST: http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing things RESTfully is actually hard.

At the end of the day, the big attributes are:

1 - URIs represent resources, not actions
2 - HTTP verbs describe what action to take

ie:

GETing http://www.example.com/something/1 will return the something identified by 1
POSTing http://www.example.com/something/1 will update it
PUTing http://www.example.com/something will create a new something

3 - The responses to things like GET requests should document other places the client can go.

If a client asks for http://www.example.com/movies/1 (via GET), the response should contain elements that point the client to things related.  Like http://www.examples.com/review/movie/1 (which might list reviews of movie #1

This is really rough -- spend a day googling around and reading.  Then try to figure out who's really talking about REST, and who's confusing it with basic RPC stuff with simplified URL schemes.

Comment: It seems that POSTing to http://www.example.com/something/1 will create a subordinate of 'something' identified by 1, i.e. POST treats 'something' as a collection

PUTing http://www.example.com/something will replace the collection of 'something' with a new collection

there's a table in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services which explains different combinations of URIs and methods

Answer (score 1):

To start with, a RESTful web service must not violate any of the following constraints (described in detail in Roy Fielding's [seminal dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm)):

- client-server
- stateless
- cacheable
- uniform interface
- layered system

Of these, 'uniform interface' is particularly important.

Answer (score 0):

A plain MVC partterns is good.

Also you have to make sure you split your things into real model (for example for a blog it would be post/comments)

Also you have to use all the HTTP verb so PUT/DELETE/POST/GET.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question: [Representational State Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Constraints)

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental consideration in REST is to strictly observe the division between "side effect free" methods and ones with side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Understanding the [difference between PUT and POST](http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/put-or-post-the-rest-of-the-story/), aka understanding what idempotency means.
2. REST != RPC. There seems to be a lot of resources on the web (such as [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/omarzabir/archive/2008/10/03/create-rest-api-using-asp-net-mvc-that-speaks-both-json-and-plain-xml.aspx)) that seems to think that just because there are multiple representations of a resource, then it is restful. Links such as /API/User/GetUser are not restful.

Answer (score 0):

[Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) (HATEOAS). Interpreting REST with a clear grasp of this single constraint will make everything else about REST an order of magnitude easier to understand.